# C# JSON.NET reading string from JArray results in Blank string?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I basically have a dynamic JSON object which contains a property called SectionIDs which is a JArray of strings.

```
"SectionIDs": [
          "974ec4d7-ef2c-49cf-9ae9-4061ea832797",
          "974ec4d7-ef2c-49cf-9ae9-4061ea832797",
          "974ec4d7-ef2c-49cf-9ae9-4061ea832797"
           ]
```

However, I cannot seem to get a reference on this data.

Consider this test code:

```
//section list
JArray jsonSectionArray = (JArray)levelObject.SectionIDs;

for (j = 0; j < jsonSectionArray.Count; j++)
{
     Console.WriteLine("APPENDED : " + (string)jsonSectionArray[j]);
     Console.WriteLine("DIRECT CAST: ", (string)jsonSectionArray[j]);

     sectionID = (string)jsonSectionArray[j];

     Console.WriteLine("JSON: ", sectionID);
}
```

Why is "APPENDED" the only non blank output?

```
APPENDED : 974ec4d7-ef2c-49cf-9ae9-4061ea832797
DIRECT CAST: 
JSON:
```

The original problem was that I was looping through my sections to find the section with the same ID, but:

```
private SectionView getSectionByID(string id){
    //always id == " "
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Console.WriteLine` line has a typo:

```
Console.WriteLine("DIRECT CAST: ", (string)jsonSectionArray[j]);
```

should be:

```
Console.WriteLine("DIRECT CAST: " + (string)jsonSectionArray[j]);
// ------------------------------/\
```

or:

```
Console.WriteLine("DIRECT CAST: {0}", (string)jsonSectionArray[j]);
```

Comment: Wow I am embarrassed. I would never have guessed the {0}. What does that little sprinkle of magic do?

Comment: That overload uses [composite formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd(v=vs.110).aspx) to format the string. Also check out [`string.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and direction on further reading. Appreciate it.